# Passing custom data to Hibernate Envers in Dropwizard application

Tags: java, dropwizard, hibernate-envers

I have a project in which I use `Hibernate` and I wanna use `Envers` for logging, but I need the username of who makes the changes. I've got a `Dropwizard application` and I'm using `Hibernate envers` to audit.

From the docs, I know I'm supposed to implement `RevisionListener` and set the username in `newRevision()`. However, I have no way of passing the username to the `CustomRevisionListener`. I was thinking of implementing session but then I started thinking that `Hibernate session` should differ from the `dropwizard session` and I want to pass this data within the hibernate session since I want to make sure a different username doesn't mix with a revision someone else is making.

I would appreciate any input into this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely want to read up on my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38545223/1572269).

The general idea is always the same in that you'll want your application to store a `ThreadLocal` variable that contains the pertinent information the listener needs and then access that `ThreadLocal` variable within the listener callback.  Its worth noting there is no threading concerns as all of Envers happens within the same thread context of the hibernate session itself.

My suggestion would be to make your `ThreadLocal` variable a top level class that you set properties on so that should it need to be extended in the future or reused across implementations, you could easily do so.

Comment: I am stuck in the same proble, using dropwizard and hibernate envers, and I have tried out the approach you mentioned but the new revision table is not getting created. should i create it manually, so that it works because right now the data is going to the default REVINFO table