# Hibernate Envers: Log user ip address

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

Im looking to log the IP address of the current user in my audit tables, currently this is done like `InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString()` which is wrongly logging the server IP.

Usually I could do this through autowiring an HttpRequest object but this isn't possible inside the `newRevision()` method I am overriding in my listener.

Comment: In order to know the client ip address as you say the only way is with the request, if you don't have accesible your request but you use the thread to precess the request and do your logic you can store this data inside a thread holder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527608/extending-hibernate-envers-implementation) post.

In a web application, the best place for setting a `ThreadLocal` variable would typically be inside something like a `Filter` or `Interceptor`, basically any component-like code that runs prior to any of the web request handler's code, guaranteeing that the `ThreadLocal` variable has been set.

Then you simply access that `ThreadLocal` inside your Envers revision entity listener and populate the custom field with the value.

Just be sure to clear the `ThreadLocal` variable at the end of the request handler chain.