# How to save additional attributes when using envers

Tags: java, hibernate-envers

I'm using Hibernate Envers for my revision history. 
This is my table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE EPIC (
epicid SERIAL NOT NULL,
accountid BIGINT NOT NULL, 
description TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
epicowner TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(epicid)
);

CREATE TABLE EPIC_AUD(
epicid BIGINT NOT NULL ,
REV BIGINT NOT NULL,
accountid BIGINT,
description TEXT,
epicowner TEXT,
REVTYPE BIGINT,
PRIMARY KEY(epicid,REV)
);
```

Currently when i make changes it only saves the composite primary key values and the revision type. Since i also want to log the user who deleted some entity, i want to save that value too. This is the code i'm using for deleting the entity.

```
@Override
public boolean deleteItem(Epic epicFromFrontend) {
    transactionBegin();
    Epic epicToRemove = getEntityManager().find(Epic.class,  epicFromFrontend.getEpicid());
    epicToRemove.setAccountid(epicFromFrontend.getAccountid());
    getEntityManager().remove(epicToRemove);
    return transactionEnd();
}
```

Actually i have 2 questions:

1. How to save the accountid too
2. Or is it maybe smarter and better to save ALL data. so i have no empty fields in my EPIC_AUD table after a delete.

Comment: Something like http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#d0e5519 might help you achieve what you want if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your response but that's something i already found. However i'm not a big fan of that because that means that i have to create al lot of code for just doing a simple thing. I'm wondering if there aren't any annotations like "@Auditthisattribute" or @Auditthisfield

Comment: What you're honestly looking for is to track something pertinent at the RevisionEntity level and not track values at the domain entity level.  That allows you to track the deletion user easily without any intrusive code to manipulate your domain model.

Answer (score 3):

It is a common practice to capture various additional pieces of information that is audit-specific during the insert, update, or delete of your domain entities.

A simple yet intrusive way is to store that state in the same structure as the entity, as suggested by Marcin H.  While this approach may work, there are several problems with this approach.

1. **Mixing Concerns**
   The problem here is that historical related information is now being stored right along side the domain specific data.  Much like security, auditing is a cross cutting concern and thus should be treated in the same way when it comes to data structures.  Additionally, as multiple audited rows in your schema are manipulated, you often represent the same user, timestamp, etc across multiple tables which lead to unnecessary schema and table bloat.
2. **Unnecessary fields / operations for data removal**
   When you store fields of this calibur on the entity itself, it introduces an interesting set of requirements as a part of the entity removal process.  If you want Envers to track that removal user then  you either have to perform an entity update with that user prior to removal or introduce an additional column to track whether a row is soft deleted, as suggested by Marcin H.
   This approach means that a table will always grow indefinitely, even when delete has been removed.  It could have negative impacts to long-term query performance and other various concerns.  Ideally, if data is no longer relevant except from a historical purpose and no FK relationships continue to exist that must be maintained, its far better to remove the row from the non-audit table.

Rather than the above, I suggest using this strategy I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38545223/1572269) that describes how to leverage a custom *RevisionEntity* data structure with Envers, allowing you to track multiple columns of data that is pertinent to the current transaction operation.

This approach has the following added benefits:

1. No Envers (audit) specific code littered across your DAO methods.  Your DAO methods continue to focus on the domain specific operation only, as it should be.
2. In situations where multiple entities are manipulated during a single transaction, you now only capture the various audit-attributes once per transaction (aka once per revision).  This means if the user adds, removed, and updates various rows, they'll all be tagged once.
3. You now can easily track the person who performed the row deletion because the audit attributes are kept on the *RevisionEntity*, which will be generated for the deletion.  No special operations or fields are needed to handle this case.  Furthermore, you can enable storing the entity snapshot at deletion and then have access to (1) who deleted the row and (2) what the row looked like prior to the removal too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i'll think i'm gonna give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can add attribue **record_active boolean** to your table epic, as well as to table **epic_aud** of course.
When *record_active* is *false* it means record has been "deleted".
And never remove any record physically - it's good practice in fact :)

Comment: Thats something i also had in mind but then my attributes in the table epic_aud are still having null values.

Comment: Why? When some user wants to delete record, your application set **record_status** to *false* and **account_id** to *id* of that user. Envers creates copy of the record with record_status and account_id as current values. Nothing is lost, and you just have to filter records using record_status to ignore "deleted" items.

Comment: Maybe i'm to stupid to understand you but al NON-PK values in the table epic aren't saved in the table epic_aud. e.g. If I delete one row it just fills the attributes: epicid, rev and revtype. If i would add a attribute so called record_status and i put that to false. the false value isn't showed in record in epic_aud

Comment: But whole point is that you don't delete any record (at least in that table). You don't use EntityManager.remove(...) method. You just set **record_active** to false, persist it and treat this value as if record has been realy removed (but it isn't).

Comment: If you put it in that way it's indeed a good practice but that in that way i am just persisting everything and i'm getting rid of all the delete methods

Comment: At least for a tables for which you want to keep complete history including full history of user activities. For some cases it works, but of course it isn't general solution.

Comment: BTW you can still use your method deleteItem(...) but inside its body set **record_activity** to *false* and invoke EntityManager.persist(...) instead remove(...)

Comment: Copy that! Thank you sir. Although you helped me i'm still wondering if there isn't any other way. I'm going to use your idea until something else pops up

Comment: So if you find some interesting solution put it in comment here, thanks!

Comment: There are cases where a soft-delete field is useful, particularly where Foreign Key relationships must be maintained between entities; however using one for this case is very intrusive.  A better solution would be to leverage the features of Envers for this situation as I described in my answer to better solve the problem.