# Catch username from spring web application to use by trigger

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, triggers

I would like to save in my database information about history, for example user "dog" edited field "grass" in table "garden".

I have trigger which saves everything correctly but I have problem with username "dog". Username is logged user's name and I don't now how to "catch" it, because I don't know how to tell my database (PostgreSQL) that this specific user did that.

How can I tell my trigger that it should use value "dog"?

I would like to write an application in Java using Spring Framework and Hibernate Framework. I haven't any app code, because now I'm creating database and thinking about my future application.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For certain database platforms, they offer context parameters.  To use these, you would:

1. Set the database context parameters.
   You can simply use the native SQL interface exposed by `Session` or `EntityManager` to accomplish this step.
2. Register an `AfterTransactionCompletionProcess` with the `Session`.
   This should basically use the provided `Session` and clear the database context parameters which you set as part of (1).  You would want to do this regardless of whether the transaction was successful or not.  This step makes sure those context parameters are cleared prior to giving the JDBC connection back to your connection pool.
3. Execute your normal ORM changes.

But there is probably a much simplier approach all together, called Hibernate Envers.

Hibernate Envers is designed to mirror your mapped `@Entity` classes and keep a running history of changes made to your entities.  You can easily configure the fields you'd like audited should there only be a subset of fields you're interested in the history on.  Additionally, the Envers API exposes an easy way for you to query the history tables and get historical snapshots.

In order to store your username `"dog"` with Hibernate Envers, you would need to merely implement a custom `RevisionEntity` that contains your `userName` field and set it.  You can find more information on how to configure the necessary components for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527608/extending-hibernate-envers-implementation/38545223#38545223).